# Lazy Loading: How to create a lazy loading html page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

I wanted to have a page that load the content only when it reached that section by scrolling, just like what pinterest website was doing.

What is the design of implementing it or are there a plugin to do that? Please help.

Comment: I've heard it referred to as infinite scrolling. You might want to search for tutorials on that.

Comment: Oh yea you are right... infinite scrolling.

Comment: What have you tried? This has two pieces--Figuring out when the user has reached a point on the page and loading and appending the new data. Check out the waypoints plugin if you're having trouble with the first part.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).on( "scroll" , function() {

     var $document = $(document);
     var $window = $(this);

     if( $document.scrollTop() >= $document.height() - $window.height() - 400 ) {
         // do something
     }

 });
```

Where 400 is your offset from the bottom of the page. There are plugins that do this but this is some simple code to do it. I recommend using underscorejs to throttle this function because this function will fire every time the scroll top changes. So for every pixel it will trigger. Generally I throttle it to only run every 60 frames per second.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery if you want to try that:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload